# pthread_t is in android and linux

Tags: android, c, linux, pthreads, android-source

I'm new to android. Checked in android pthread_t is defined as typedef long int pthread_t, I am not sure how it is defined in Linux. If it is defined to native datatype, and it difference from android, they why is that difference?

Comment: typedef unsigned long int pthread_t; Some version of Red Hat, not sure exactly which.

Comment: Well I can't check that at work, but I think it's likely to be the same. I just checked on whichever server I happened to be logged in to.

Comment: Your question is "Why is `unsigned` missing from Android `typedef` right? If I get you correctly? Cos its `typedef unsigned long int pthread_t` in Linux and `typedef unsigned long int pthread_t` in Android headers

Answer (score 1):

It's defined in bits/pthreadtypes.h as unsigned long int - it's thread descriptor, but why does it matter to you?

Comment: I have ported windows version code to linux, where in i used typedef unsigned long int pthread_t; so that same can code can be used for both windows and linux. Now i want to port to android, thought of using same typedef, but was showing me the error!.

Comment: You're `typedef`ing it yourself? You should use the header, and maybe create your own for Windows.

Comment: in windows version code, wherever threadid is used defined as unsigned long int, so instead of using two sets of code, i typedefed unsigned long int for linux.

Comment: I'm almost sure it's implementation dependant, so you can't rely on it to be unchanged between library updates. In theory, it can be a pointer too. I'd prefer to typedef my own type to either pthread_t or whatever else target operating system provides, within OS-identifying #ifdef's.

Answer (score 0):

There might be different requirements for different platforms, and the native types are different on various implementations, so using a typedef makes sense.

For example `long` is 32 bits on 64-bit Windows but 64 bits on 64-bit Linux.